# Estoy usando material ui con react y quiero que al hacer click en el componente de react Async select el label suba tal cual si fuese un TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Cuando se da clic en el componente para empezar una búsqueda el label desaparece y la idea es que el label suba al borde del componente tal cual lo hace cuando se usa un TextFiel o un Imput de material ui.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

class Autocomplete extends Component {

  render() {
    const {id, name, label, placeholder, value, isClearable, autoFocus,cacheOptions, loadOptions, onChange, disabled, ...other } = this.props;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <AsyncSelect
        .......
          value={value}
          render={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label={label}
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth

            />
          )}
          {...other}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default Autocomplete;
```

[image: comportamiento de react async select]
[image: comportamiento en un TextField]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo estas usando un componente que no es de Material UI y quieres que se comporte como uno. En mi opinión la única forma de lograr eso es crear un nuevo componente con el comportamiento deseado. Material UI no brinda ninguna API para hacer lo que deseas.

Comment: Es correcto el componente que necesito modificar no es de material ui es de react la cuestión es que no logro simular el comportamiento del label para que funcione según los componentes de material ui y no tengo la opción de sustituir el componente por uno de material ui ya que esta demasiado arraigado en el sistema.